# Producing every combination of columns from one pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'd like to take a dataframe and visualize how useful each column is in a k-neighbors analysis so I was wondering if there was a way to loop through dropping columns and analyzing the dataframe in order to produce an accuracy for every single combination of columns. I'm really not sure if there are some functions in pandas that I'm not aware of that could make this easier or how to loop through the dataframe to produce every combination of the original dataframe. If I have not explained it well I will try and create a diagram.

a | b | c |                | labels |

1 | 2 | 3 |                |   0    |

5 | 6 | 7 |                |   1    |

The dataframe above would produce something like this after being run through the splitting and k-neighbors function:

a & b = 43%

a & c = 56%

b & c = 78%

a & b & c = 95%

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us understand your question, please provide a [mcve]. For example, how did you derive a & b = 43% ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
min_size = 2
max_size = df.shape[1]
column_subsets = itertools.chain(*map(lambda x: itertools.combinations(df.columns, x), range(min_size,max_size+1)))
for column_subset in column_subsets:
     foo(df[list(column_subset)])
```

where `df` is your dataframe and `foo` is whatever kNA you're doing. Although you said "all combinations", I put `min_size` at 2 since your example has only size >= 2. And these are more precisely referred to as "subsets" rather than "combinations".

Comment: Excellent I'll give this a go but it looks like you've understood my question and this looks like the exact sort of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: I tried this answer out and it seems there is a syntax error somewhere in line 4

Comment: Yeah I figured that part out. Thank you very much for your answer you definitely point me in the right direction